# discordjs/voice: Changing volume does not have any effect

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js, opus

I'm using @discordjs/voice for a bot. When I try to change the audio volume of a resource, no matter if it's while the resource is being played currently or if I do it before playing it, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

My code for creating the resource looks like this:

```js
const stream = ytdl(url, {
    filter: "audioonly",
    format: "mp3",
    highWaterMark: 1 << 62,
    liveBuffer: 1 << 62,
    dlChunkSize: 0,
    bitrate: 128,
    quality: "lowestaudio"
})
const resource = createAudioResource(stream, {inlineVolume: true});
```

And for changing the volume before playing:

```js
resource.volume.setVolume(audioVolume);
audioPlayer.play(resource);
```

I've tried `audioVolume` values between 0.0-1.0 as well as between 0-100 but no matter the value, the audio volume stayed exactly the same. Any Ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried using `setVolumeLogarithmic()` since humans perceive logarithmically? There is more information in the [`prism-media` docs](https://amishshah.github.io/prism-media/core.VolumeTransformer).

Comment: Hey @wgumenyuk, even though I managed to fix the issue, using logarithmic scaling for the volume seems to be a good idea. Thanks for the info!

Comment: That's great to hear, good luck in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I wasn't calling the function with the code for changing the value correctly, which means the code didn't get executed. Seems like this was an issue with some other part of my code, after making sure the `setVolume()` method actually gets called, it worked.